# Is the definition of the canonical projection given wrong ? If so, is there any problem in my correction?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, direct-sum, direct-product

In the [book](http://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4%E2%80%A6) of *linear algebra* by Werner Greub, at page $59$ it is given that

[image]

and from this definition, he argues that

[image]

However, by the definition of $\pi_\varrho$, whatever the map $x \in \oplus_\alpha E_\alpha$ is, it will map it to $x_\varrho$, so in $2.25$ if $\sigma$ is different from $\varrho$, then the composition will take any $x_\sigma$ any map it to $x_\varrho$, which indicates $2.25$ is wrong, so from this argument, I thought the definition of $\pi_\varrho$ is not complete and tried to redefine it by
$$\pi_\varrho (x_\alpha) = \delta_\alpha^\varrho * x_\varrho.$$

So the my question is that is my argument correct ? and also is my correction correct ? If not, what is the problem.

Note: I normally don't like to post a question with pictures, but while studying and trying to find an answer to some problems, it is really annoying to type everything every time if you are asking such questions regularly, so I'm hoping that it will not cause any problem.

**Edit:**

**I think what I don't understand is that how is $x_\varrho$ in $2.24$ is determined.**

Comment: The composition $E_a \to \bigoplus_i E_i \to E_b$ is zero if $a \neq b$

Comment: @N.H. and your point is ? I mean the indices of $i$ and $\pi$ are different.

Comment: @N.H. Also see my edit.

Comment: The definition is fine. You just use the Kronecker delta, right?

Comment: @Wuestenfux Yes it is the Kronecker delta, but how it is OK. I mean what is wrong in my argument then ?

Comment: The argument of $\pi_\rho$ is an element $x\in \oplus_iE_i$.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Thanks you for pointing out, but I don't see how it makes my argument wrong ?

Comment: You've written $\pi_\rho(x_\alpha)$ which is misleading since $x_\alpha\in\oplus_i E_i$.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Whether is it $x$ or $x_\alpha$, it always maps them to $x_\varrho$, so what is your point ?

Comment: @Wuestenfux Plus, the elements of the vector space $\oplus_\alpha E_\alpha$ are of the form $x_\alpha  ( \alpha) \in E_\alpha$, so I think writing $x_\alpha$ instead of $x$ make the definition much clearer.

Comment: @OnurcanB. No , the elements of $\oplus E_\alpha$ are the functions $x: A \to \cup_\alpha E_\alpha$, satisfying (i) and (ii). And $\pi_\alpha(x)$ is just $x(\alpha)$, simple as that.

Comment: @OnurcanB. You can think of $x \in E_\alpha$ as also being in $\oplus_\alpha E_\alpha$ as $i_\alpha(x)$. $x \notin \oplus_\alpha E_\alpha$ but $i_\alpha(x) \in \oplus_\alpha E_\alpha$. Also, $i_\alpha$ is a linear isomorphism between $E_\alpha$ and its image in $\oplus_\alpha E_\alpha$. So people often identify $x$ and $i_\alpha(x)$, but sometimes more precision is called for.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma How do you understand $\pi_\alpha (x) = x(\alpha)$. I mean there is nothing indicating such thing as far as I see.

Comment: @OnurcanB. just under condition (ii) it says "We denote $x(\alpha)$ by $x_\alpha$" Then 2.24 is just saying that projection is what I said it is.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma You are right, thanks a lot.By the way, I really liked _Topology Atlas_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider what $\pi_\rho \circ i_\sigma$ is: it maps a point in $x \in E_\sigma$ to the function $i_\sigma(x)$ from $A \to \cup_\alpha E_\alpha$ that is $0$ for **all** $\alpha \neq \sigma$, so $i_\sigma(x)(\alpha) =0$ for $\alpha \neq \sigma$ and $i_\sigma(x)(\sigma) = x$.

Some motivation: $\oplus_\alpha E_\alpha$ can be seen as a formal sum of the vector spaces $E_\alpha$ : pick finitely many $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ from $A$ and a point $x_{\alpha_i} \in E_{\alpha_i}$ for $i=1,\ldots, n$ and we consider all such elements $x_{\alpha_1} + \ldots + x_{\alpha_n}$ as elements of $\oplus_\alpha E_\alpha$, but note that the sum is meaningless a priori. One $E_\alpha$ could be $\mathbb{R}^3$ and another $\mathbb{R}^4$ etc. We cannot *really* add them in a sum like that. So we consider these as "formal" sums, that we just compute with. To multiply a sum by a scalar, just do this for every summand, and we can add to finite formal sums just by collecting terms that happen to be in the same $E_\alpha$ (where thay *can* be added properly), and leaving terms from different ones as they were. The trick with defining it as the text is a constructive way to make this more exact: the above formal sum $x_{\alpha_1} + \ldots + x_{\alpha_n}$ corresponds to the function $x$ that sends $\alpha_i$ to $x_{\alpha_i}$ for all finitely many $i$ and to the $0$ of $E_\alpha$ for all other $\alpha$. We only take finite sums, hence condition (ii). We can think of any element as an infinite sum, in a way, namely we pick $0$ for all $\alpha$ that are not in our finite sum $x_{\alpha_1} + \ldots + x_{\alpha_n}$.. So $i_\sigma(x)$, for $x \in E_\sigma$ in this light is just the formal sum $x$ (just one term) with $0$ everywhere except $\sigma$.

The function $\pi_\alpha$ goes back to the individual $E_\alpha$ again. For any finite formal sum we can still distinguish the individual vectors (because we never really add them, except within an original vector space), so $\pi_\alpha(x_{\alpha_1} + \ldots + x_{\alpha_n}) = x_{\alpha_i}$ if $\alpha = \alpha_i$ and $0$ if $\alpha \notin \{\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n\}$ (because we work under the idea we have $0$ for every unmentioned index). Formally,when $x$ is a function from $A$ to $\sum_\alpha E_\alpha$, we just define $\pi_\alpha(x) = x(\alpha)$: all elements of $\oplus_\alpha E_\alpha$ are functions from $A$, so we just take the value at $\alpha$, which lies in $E_\alpha$ by condition (i).

So now $\pi_\rho(i_\sigma)$ has two cases: $\sigma \neq \rho$: $i_\sigma(x)$ is the function that sends $\sigma$ to $x$ and all other indices, to $0$. So $i_\sigma(x)(\rho) = 0 = \pi_\rho(i_\sigma(x))$. For $\sigma=\rho$ we just get $x$ again: $\pi_\sigma(i_\sigma(x)) = i_\sigma(x)(\sigma) = x$ by definition. We first make a trivial sum with only $x \in E_\sigma$ and then ask: what is the part from $E_\sigma$? Well, $x$ again, clearly.

Your $x_\rho$ is just $x(\rho)$, as well. In this setup members of $\oplus_{\alpha \in A} E_\alpha$ are special functions on $A$ (You pick $x(\alpha)$ from $\cup_\alpha E_\alpha$. but you have to choose $0 \in E_\alpha$ almost all of the time, we only have finitely many "real choices" to make, because we only want to do finite formal sums (we could define infinite ones as well). In 2.26 it looks like we do infinite sums, but for every $x$ in $\oplus_\alpha E_\alpha$ the sum is really a finite one.